# Why does $U(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle= e^{i \theta}|0\rangle$ hold ? i.e. time evolution of vacuum is still a vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, vacuum

In quantum field theory, we always use $U(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle= e^{i \theta}|0\rangle$, where $$U(+\infty,-\infty)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow +0} \mathcal{T}\exp\{i \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-\epsilon|t'|} H_i(t') dt\}$$ 
That is we adiabatically switch on the interaction and then switch off. My question is why the infinite time evolution of free vacuum is still a free vacuum? Can anyone explain in the following  case ?

In the case, the field is massless like Maxwell field. I know there is adiabatic theorem in quantum mechanics, but it requires there is always a gap from the orginal state. But in QED, above the vacuum these is a continuous spectrum since photon is massless.  Why $U(+\infty,-\infty)|0\rangle= e^{i \theta}|0\rangle$ still holds?

The same problem also exists in the condensed matter field where the spectra of phonon is gapless. Why does every qft textbook or quantum many-body textbook just say it's an adiabatic theorem?

If this equation is not correct, then we cannot get the following formula:

$$\langle\Omega|\mathcal{T}A(t_1)B(t_2)\cdots|\Omega\rangle=\frac{\langle 0|\mathcal{T} U(+\infty,-\infty)A(t_1)B(t_2)\cdots| 0\rangle}{\langle 0| U(+\infty,-\infty) | 0\rangle}$$

Comment: In massless theories that equation does not hold. But massless theories are ill-defined anyway, so you have to introduce an IR regulator that generates a mass-gap. So: in practice, massless theories are not really massless; they are to be regulated.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Can you recommend  any textbook talk about this?  How to rigorously tackle this problem?

Comment: see for example the references in  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/330220/84967

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208802/free-vacuum-vs-interacting-vacuum-and-wicks-theorem , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210119/scattering-perturbation-and-asymptotic-states-in-lsz-reduction-formula